# Questions about Sylow $p$-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

**Question 1** Is it true that there is only one Sylow $p$-group in an abelian group?

**Question 2** If there is only one Sylow $p$-group, then it is normal, true? Because if $H\leq G$ is a Sylow $p$-group then so is $gHg^{-1}$, hence $H=gHg^{-1}$ by uniquness?

**Question 3** Can someone please give me an example of a Sylow $p$-group in some group which is *not* normal?

Answer (score 6):

Question $1$ is true, if $P$ and $Q$ are $p$-sylow subgroups then they are conjugate. In an abelian group every subgroup is normal.

Question $2$ is true, if you conjugate a $P$-sylow subgroup you get another (because they have the same order), so if there is only one then the subgroup is invariant under conjugation, hence normal.

Question $3$: any group in which there is more than one Sylow $p$-subgroup, For example $S_3$ and $p=2$.

Comment: Oh, so if there's more than 1 Sylow $p$-group then none of them is normal? Why is that so?

Comment: it is because if $P$ and $Q$ are $p$-sylow subgroups then there exists $g$ so that $P=gQg^{-1}$. It is part of the sylow theorems.

Comment: Right and this is never $gPg^{-1}$? @CarryonSmiling

Comment: a subgroup is normal if and only if $gPg^{-1}=P$ for all $g\in G$.  If there exists a $P$ sylows subgroup $Q$ other than $P$ then there exist $g$ so that $gPg^{-1}=Q\neq P$, so $P$ is not normal.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes: in an abelian group every subgroup is normal.
2. Correct.
3. The group $A_5$ is simple and it has $60$ elements. Then $\langle(1,2,3,4)\rangle$ is a Sylow $2$-group and it is not normal.

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by $(1,2,3,4)$?

Comment: It is a cycle. It maps $1$ to $2$, $2$ to $3$, $3$ to $3$ and $4$ to $1$. It maps $5$ to itself.

Comment: @ajotatxe Exactly, that's a cycle, *not* a subgroup...and that cycle is *not* in $\;A_4\;$, though it is in $\;S_4\;$ .